# Javascripts not working on Heroku Rails 4.2 deploy with Zurb Foundation 5, but work in development

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, zurb-foundation-5

I'm running Rails 4.2.3 with the 'foundation-rails' 5.5.2 gem and am not able to get it running on Heroku. My app is working fine locally, but when trying to deploy my app to Heroku with Foundation 5 the javascripts are not loading.

The CSS looks ok on Heroku, but things like modals are not working, and the console doesn't show that there are any javascripts running that were specified in my `application.js` file.

`Modernizr.js` and `Jquery-2.1.4` are running

I'm not seeing any errors anywhere, and I have precompiled assets using `bundle exec rake assets:precompile` and the assets appear to have been precompiled.

How do I get the javascripts to load so that the page will work properly?

**application.js:**

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery.serializeJSON
//= require jquery.bind_with_delay
//= require_tree .
//= require_self
//= require gifffer.min
//= require imagesloaded.min
//= require google.jsapi
//= require foundation
//= stub bookmarklet/modal_bookmarklet
$(function() { 
  $(document).foundation();
});
```

**production.rb**

```
config.cache_classes = true

config.eager_load = true

config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

config.serve_static_files = true

config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier

config.assets.compile = true

config.assets.digest = true
```

**gemfile**

```
source "https://rubygems.org"

gem "rails", "4.2.3"
gem "unicorn"
gem "mysql2", ">= 0.3.14"
gem "pg"
gem "thinking-sphinx", "~> 3.1.2"
gem "jquery-rails"
gem "dynamic_form"
gem "exception_notification"
gem "bcrypt", "~> 3.1.2"
gem "nokogiri", "= 1.6.6.2"
gem 'mini_portile', '~>0.6.2'
gem "htmlentities"
gem "rdiscount"
gem "oauth"
gem "mail"
gem 'metainspector', :git => 'https://github.com/jaimeiniesta/metainspector.git'
gem 'material_icons'
gem "bower-rails","~> 0.9.2"
gem 'launchy'
gem 'sass', '~> 3.4.15'
gem 'foundation-rails', '~> 5.5.2'
gem 'compass', '~>1.0.3'
gem "uglifier", ">= 1.3.0"
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
gem 'modernizr-rails', '~>2.7.1'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.3.0'
gem 'multi_json', '~>1.11.1'

gem 'rails_12factor'
gem 'paperclip', :git => "git://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip.git"
gem 'aws-sdk'
gem 'figaro'
gem 'omniauth-facebook'

gem 'pg_search'
gem 'kaminari'
gem 'ejs'

gem 'yt', '~> 0.25.0'

group :doc do
    gem 'sdoc', require: false
end

group :test, :development do
  gem "rspec-rails", "~> 3.3.2"
  gem "machinist"
  gem "sqlite3"
  gem "faker"
  gem 'annotate'
  gem 'better_errors'
  gem 'binding_of_caller'
end
```

**edit**
It looks like I'm getting an error that says "Uncaught TypeError: $(...).foundation is not a function". I'm not sure if this is related to Heroku or my configuration. Why would this work locally, and not on Heroku?

Comment: Are you certain your precompiled assets are getting into your repository so that they are available to Heroku during deploy?

Comment: I think so. I can see them in the public/assets/vendor folder.

Comment: And are they getting pushed to your repository?  You should verify that the repository includes these files.

Comment: I used `heroku run bash` and confirmed they're in the heroku repository.

Comment: It looks like I'm getting an error that says "Uncaught TypeError: $(...).foundation is not a function. I'm not sure if this is related to Heroku or my configuration. Why would this work locally, and not on Heroku?

Comment: You have your `require_self` call before you load the foundation JS and you are trying to use the foundation JS in your manifest file.  Try moving the `require_self` directive after all of your other directives.

Comment: Of course. I should've caught that. Thank you! If you want to post that as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have your `require_self` call before you load the foundation JS and you are trying to use the foundation JS in your manifest file. Try moving the `require_self` directive after all of your other directives.